# monomial vector in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose that you have a vector a tuple $a$, I want to define a function p(x)=x^a in julia.

For example, if a=(1,2,3), the resultant function would be x^1 *y^2 * z^3.

I would like to have a general method for any tuple, however I don't know the appropiate notation. In my code, I have an array of tuples and I want to define a monomial for each tuple in the array.

Thank you very much for your collaboration.

Comment: Bogumil's answer is the properly constructed option. But a one-line option: `metap(a) = (args...)->prod(args.^a)` also works i.e. `metap((2,1,1))(2,3,5) == 60`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> function genmonomial(t::Tuple{Vararg{Integer}})
           @assert !isempty(t) && all(>=(0), t)
           return (x...) -> begin
               @assert length(x) == length(t)
               return mapreduce(x -> x[1]^x[2], *, zip(x, t))
           end
       end
genmonomial (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f = genmonomial((2,3,4))
#1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(2, 1, 1)
4

julia> f(1, 2, 1)
8

julia> f(1, 1, 2)
16

julia> f(2, 2, 2)
512

julia> f(1, 1)
ERROR: AssertionError: length(x) == length(t)

julia> genmonomial(())
ERROR: AssertionError: !(isempty(t)) && all((>=)(0), t)

julia> genmonomial((1.5,))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching genmonomial(::Tuple{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  genmonomial(::Tuple{Vararg{Integer}}) at REPL[1]:1
```